# Webview Is Not Showing App Bar

Tags: android, webview

I'm using the below code to launch the `WebView` from my application. My whole app uses a top bar with left side menu, however when i run this `webview` top bar and left side menu hides. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(result.getText());
```

This is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.sherdle.universal.qrcodeactivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeBar"></activity>
```

Style

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeBar" parent="AppTheme">
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/Toolbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Toolbar_Title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar_Popup" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar_Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CardActionButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/card_button</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">4.0dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyle">
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyleNoPadding">
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: will you share your AppThemeBar style?

Comment: you have used theme with NoActionBar so you'll have to add Toolbar